# updating and modeling nosql record

Tags: mongodb, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

So in a traditional database I might have 2 tables like users, company

| id | username | companyid | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | j23 | 1 | something@gmail.com |
| 2 | fj222 | 1 | james@aol.com |

| id | ownerid | company_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A Really boring company |

This is to say that user 1 and 2 are apart of company 1 (a really boring company) and user 1 is the owner of this company.

I could easily issue an update statement in MySQL or Postgresql to update the company name.

But how could I model the same data from a NoSQL perspective, in something like Dynamodb or Mongodb?

Would each user record (document in NoSQL) contain the same company table data (id, ownerid (or is owner true/false, and company name)? I'm unclear how to update the record for all users containing this data then if the company name needed to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to save the company object as JSON in each field (for performance reasons), indeed, you have to update a lot of rows.

But best way to achieve this is to have a similar structure as you have above, in MySQL. NoSql schema depends a lot on the queries you will be making.

For example, the schema above is great for:

- Find a particular user by username, along with his company name. First you need to query `User` by `username` (you can add an index), get the `companyId` and do another query on `Company` to fetch the name.
- Let's assume company name changes often
- In this case company name update is easy. To execute the read query, you need 2 queries to get your result (but they should execute fast)

Embedded company JSON would work better for:

- Find all users from a specific city and show their company name
- Let's assume company name changes very rarely
- In this case, we can't use the "relational" approach, because we will do 1 query to fetch `User`s by `city` and then another query for all users found to fetch the company name
- Using embedded approach, we need only 1 query
- To update a company name, a full (expensive) scan is needed, but should be ok if done rarely

What if company name changes ofter and I want to get users by city?

- This becomes tricky, NoSQL is not a replacement for SQL, it has it's shortcomings. Solution may be a platform dependent feature (from mongo, dynamodb, firestore etc.), an additional layer above (elasticSearch) or no solution at all (consider not using key-value NoSQL)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the programming language used to handle NoSQL objects/documents you have variety of ORM libraries to model your schema. Eg. for MongoDB plus JS/Typescript I recommend **Mongoose** and its **subdocuments**. Here is more about it:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html